# php Form varibles

Tags: php, mysql, post

I want someone to tell me what is wrong with this code.

Am making a form but the variables are not inserting in sql table of users

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(first,last,user,password)
VALUES('$first','$last','$user','$pwd')";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Comment: can you include the contents of dbh.php? and are you sure you are sending the form via POST?

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: All fields names are keywords, cool

Comment: cbo, nope ain't getting any error its just that when I check the table I find it empty

Comment: First place this at the top of your PHP file - `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, see if you get any error then.  Secondly `$pwd = $_POST[ 'password' ]`??? No, you need to hash the password or you are inserting plain text, that is not good.